# Conditional Formatting for all rows with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to solve a problem.
How to apply conditional formatting not for individual cells, but for the whole row by the condition of the value in the whole column.
That is, if a value is found in the column AR(AR2:AR1000) that satisfies a certain condition, then the entire row should be colored in a certain color.
So far I have the code for individual cells ready. Help please!)

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill, Font

# Import of required classes
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import CellIsRule

wb = load_workbook('pyt.xlsx')
ws = wb.active


# [A]-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Generate Fill object

# Fill in red
fill_red = PatternFill(start_color='EE1111', end_color='EE1111', fill_type='solid')
# Fill in blue
fill_blue =  PatternFill(start_color='1111EE', end_color='1111EE', fill_type='solid')

# Generate Font object (bold/white)
font = Font(bold=True, color='FFFFFF')

# [B]-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Generate CellIsRule object

# Fill cells with red and make text color white
rule1 = CellIsRule(operator='greaterThan', formula=['30.99%'], stopIfTrue=None, fill=fill_red, font=font)

# Fill cells with blue and make text color white
rule2 = CellIsRule(operator='between', formula=['0.01%', '30.99%'], stopIfTrue=None, fill=fill_blue, font=font)


# [C]-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Apply conditional formatting rules to  range of cells

ws.conditional_formatting.add('AR2:AR1000', rule1)
ws.conditional_formatting.add('AR2:AR1000', rule2)


wb.save('pyt2.xlsx')
```

I want the script to color the entire row, not a single cell.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extend the range for the Conditional Formatting to the whole row and change your formulas to TRUE/FALSE determinations.

I.e. the range `'AR2:AR1000'` will just highlight the column `'AR'`. To highlight all required cells in the row it needs to change to all columns you want to include, like `'A2 to AR1000'`.

For simplicity in explaining how to do this I've created an example with a range of just `'A1:M15'` with row 1 as the header and column G holding the percentage values to trigger the CF rules.
You should then be able to apply this to whatever size data you require on your sheet.

**Changes to code**
I have modified your code below;

1. The conditional format range `cf_range` is '$A$2:$M$15' which covers the whole range of data.
2. I have changed from using `CellIsRule` to `FormulaRule` and changed to use Excel formulas to determine if CF is to be applied, so note the import change and change in step 3.
3. Use formulas to determine a TRUE/FALSE value of the cells.

**Formulas** 
The red fill formula checks the value of the percent column in Column G if value is `greater than 0.309` equivalent to `30.9%`, returning `TRUE if greater` and `FALSE if lesser`.

```
IF($G2>0.309,TRUE,FALSE)
```

The blue fill formula checks the value of the percent column in Column G if value is `greater than 0.0001` equivalent of `0.01%` and `less than or equal to 0.309` equivalent to `30.9%`, returning `TRUE if between these values` and `FALSE if not`.

```
IF(AND($G2>0.0001,$G2<=0.309),TRUE,FALSE)
```

**Note** the cell value is the first cell in the column after the header and the `$G` fixes the CF check to column G only, hence the coordinate used in both formulas is `'$G2'`.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill, Font

# Import of required classes
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import FormulaRule  # Importing FormulaRule here

wb = load_workbook('pyt.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

# [A]-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Generate Fill object

# Fill in red
fill_red = PatternFill(start_color='EE1111', end_color='EE1111', fill_type='solid')
# Fill in blue
fill_blue = PatternFill(start_color='1111EE', end_color='1111EE', fill_type='solid')

# Generate Font object (bold/white)
font = Font(bold=True, color='FFFFFF')


# [C]-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Apply conditional formatting rules to  range of cells
### Set the range for the conditional formatting
cf_range = '$A$2:$M$15'

### Add the rules for red fill
ws.conditional_formatting.add(cf_range,
                              FormulaRule(
                                  formula=['IF($G2>0.309,TRUE,FALSE)'],
                                  stopIfTrue=None,
                                  fill=fill_red,
                                  font=font)
                              )

### Add the rules for blue fill
ws.conditional_formatting.add(cf_range,
                              FormulaRule(
                                  formula=['IF(AND($G2>0.0001,$G2<=0.309),TRUE,FALSE)'],
                                  stopIfTrue=None,
                                  fill=fill_blue,
                                  font=font)
                              )

wb.save('pyt2.xlsx')
```

The following screenshot is an example output with the Conditional Formatting applied across the range A1 - M15 
[image: Example output]

Comment: but something a little wrong with this code, cause the script is missing some values and i don't know why..

Comment: https://prnt.sc/ZiCpZF814HDv 
For example, take this screenshot, there are 30.05% values in turn, but some of them are not colored, they are missing.

Comment: oh my gosh, im so dumb, I just input the wrong values for the CF. Now it's working correctly! Thank you so much again! You're awesome!